# react-router-dom v5, replacing getComponent

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

in react v3, I have the below route where i am using getComponent to do some action dispatch stuff before rendering the component. but in v5 getComponent is not available. How can we achieve the same in v5?

```
<IndexRoute getComponent={prepare(store, Home)} />
```

prepare.js

```
const prepare = (store, component) => (
    (nextState, cb) => {

     // do some stuff

        return cb(null, component);
    }
);
```

in react v5

```
<Route exact path="/home" component={prepare(store, Home)}/>
```

Comment: Apply the logic of calling the `prepare` function in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method or a `useEffect` hook of the component that is being rendered.

Comment: Thanks Drew. But looking into the docs in detail helped me. 'getComponent' has nextState, callback whereas 'component' needs just the component to be rendered. So modified my 'prepare' function to return accordingly.  Am new to react-router, so still getting started on it.

Comment: @DrewReese Many components use prepare function, so if I move the logic to didmount, I need to update many places in the codebase. Your info helped me in the right direction, Thank you :)

Comment: I see. So this isn't really a `react-router` question then? Rather a question how to use this `prepare` function? Sorry, maybe it *is* a `react-router` question, but you just have some *very old* routing code. What is `store` in this case? Is this all just an odd way of connecting a React component to a Redux store (*or similar*)?

Comment: It is a react-router question, but as you mentioned it is old routing code. store is redux store. yes, it is just an odd way of connecting a React component to a Redux store

Comment: Why not use the [`connect` HOC](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) or the `useDispatch` and `useSelector` hooks if using Function components? Are you also using an older version of `react-redux`? I mean, it seems the basic gist of your question is something along "How can I do X from these super old versions in a newer version?" where basically we need to understand what X is to say how to do it in the current versions you want to use.

Comment: Yeah, the code is pretty running on pretty older versions, and even I am new to it, trying to figure it out. But for now, the above is resolved.